# Exposed filters -"An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator." error

Tags: 8, views, javascript

I want to change the value of "any" option's value. So I changed the value as "something" for using Jquery.

Now I click the any option, then its showing an error like

```
  An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
```

How do I change the value of 'any' without getting this error.

Comment: You cannot submit arbitrary values on some form elements that drupal does not know about. You can do that only on hidden that has #default value set but not #value. Otherwise you'll get this error and yo ucannto get around it. I suggest you ajaxify your form.

Comment: I don't want to make it as ajaxify. Is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: There isn't @logesh - the backend needs to be informed of the change to the form structure, and the only way to do that from the client-side is via AJAX